# Chinese garbled occurs while my using Qt in VS, what should I do?

Tags: visual-studio, qt

The problem occurs while reading data from a .txt file.
While my planning to output the data generally, the code should be like this:

```
ifstream input;
input.open("info.txt");
getline(input, list[i].next->name, ' ');
qDebug() << "reading file:" << QString::fromStdString(list[i].next->name);
```

But the message outputted is:

[image]

While I find many solutions from google, I make some changes:

1. Add this code at the beginning of all codes: `#pragma execution_character_set("utf-8")`
2. Change the "qDebug()..." sentence to:

   `qDebug() << "reading file:" << QString::fromLocal8Bit(QString::fromStdString(list[i].next->name).toUtf8());`

And then the result is just like this:

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow.  Remember that most of your readers will not understand Chinese characters.  It is difficult to understand what your actual problem is.  It is also difficult to understand what is happening because we don't know what the contents of `info.txt` are, or how they are encoded.  It might be helpful if you reduced `info.txt` to one line that reproduces your problem and then update your question to show the binary contents of `info.txt`; the output you get; and the output you expect.  See [tour], [ask] and [mcve] for more tips on asking effective questions.

Comment: Indicating that you have urgency with the answer will not cause you to have a quick response. Do not you think all the questions are equally urgent? That's just noise.